# Sending AsynchronousRequest with a block-the right way

Tags: objective-c

In my app i am sending a request to server .
The request is in some other class-called `requestClass`, and is being called from the main view class. (i am using cocos2d).

My question is, how would i informed the main class (from the `requestClass` ) that the operation is done ? 
When it finish the request-its callback is in its own class(`requestClass`) and the NSLog is done IN the `requestClass` .

i dont think `NSNotification` is the right way

requestClass is like :

```
[NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {

         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
             **// HOW SHOULD I INFORM THE CLASS THAT CALL ME NOW ???**

         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing ");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }

     }];
```

Comment: You can just use self here to reference the class that is running this async connection. Treat it like normal code, it's just in a block.

Comment: how would i do that. i didnt get you. the main has an instance of this request class and is calling this function. how would this function inform back LATER this instance ? i cant return it a value here ..

Comment: I mean- how can this class inform later, another class( the one who called it) that an operation is done ?

Comment: Ah, I see. To do that I'd either use delegation (i.e. set up a protocol with a function like "URLRequestDidFinish" or something). Or you could pass a block in from the original class and run that block when the request finishes.

Comment: Thanks. your ways seems right, but i dont know how to use any of them (writing the delegation or passing a block )

Comment: I'll put some code in an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, to write a delegate protocol...

Assuming your connection file is called MyRequestClass.

In MyRequestClass.h...

```
@protocol MyRequestClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)requestDidFinishWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

//in reality you would pass the relevant data from the request back to the delegate.

@end

@interface MyRequestClass : NSObject // or whatever it is

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyRequestClassDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Then in MyRequestClass.h

```
[NSURLConnection
     sendAsynchronousRequest:request
     queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                         NSData *data,
                         NSError *error)
     {

         if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
         {
             [self.delegate requestDidFinishWithDictionary:someDictionary];

             //you don't know what the delegate is but you know it has this method
             //as it is defined in your protocol.
         }
         else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
         {
             NSLog(@"Nothing ");
         }
         else if (error != nil){
             NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
         }

     }];
```

Then in whichever class you want...

In SomeOtherClass.h

```
#import "MyRequestClass.h"

@interface SomeOtherClass : UIViewController <MyRequestClassDelegate>

blah...
```

In someOtherClass.m

```
MyRequestClass *requestClass = [[MyRequestClass alloc] init];

requestClass.delegate = self;

[requestClass startRequest];
```

... and make sure to write the delegate function too...

```
- (void)requestDidFinishWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
    //do something with the dictionary that was passed back from the URL request class
}
```

Comment: no worries. There's a load of docs in the apple docs about creating protocols and delegates. This just scratches the surface.

Comment: i have this error : synthesize of weak is only allowed in arc .. it happens if i set synthesize or if i am not .

Comment: Oh, that's because you're not using ARC. I'd recommend using it. Otherwise the property should be (nonatomic, assign) instead of (nonatomic, weak).

Comment: Yes i have started without the arc, and i have lots of code so i will stay without it now. thanks again ,you really helpful .